# Rounded imageview issue android

Tags: android, rounded-corners

I am trying to get rounded border for an imageview. Here is the code for it:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/a/3292810/4224275
```

My problem is for a normal imageview declared as follows, how do I use the class object to make the image rounded. Here is my code which didn't work.

```
private ImageView imageView;
imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
imageView.buildDrawingCache();

Bitmap bmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();
ImageHelper imh = new ImageHelper();
imh.getRoundedCornerBitmap(bmap, 10);
```

It doesn't work for me. I don't know what to do.

Here is the logcat output:

[image: logcat]

Comment: did you call `imageView.setImageBitmap(imh.getRoundedCornerBitmap(bmap, 10));` ?

Comment: @Blackbelt I did just now and it still doesn't work.

Comment: what happens? Does the app crash ?

Comment: post the stacktrace of the exception

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78717/discussion-between-abhishek-singh-and-blackbelt).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in my example:

```
public class RoundedNetworkImageView extends NetworkImageView {

    public RoundedNetworkImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public RoundedNetworkImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public RoundedNetworkImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        Drawable _drawable = getDrawable();

        if (_drawable == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
            return;
        }

        Bitmap _bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)_drawable)
                .getBitmap().copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        canvas.drawBitmap(getCroppedBitmap(_bitmap, (int) (getWidth() / 1.2f)), 0,0, null);

    }

    public static Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int radius) {

        Bitmap _newBitmap;

        if(bitmap.getWidth() != radius || bitmap.getHeight() != radius) {

            _newBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, radius, radius, false);

        }
        else{

            _newBitmap = bitmap;

        }

        Bitmap _outBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(_newBitmap.getWidth(),
                _newBitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas _canvas = new Canvas(_outBitmap);

        Paint _paint = new Paint();

        Rect _rect = new Rect(0, 0, _newBitmap.getWidth(), _newBitmap.getHeight());

        _paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        _paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        _paint.setDither(true);

        _canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);

        _paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399"));

        _canvas.drawCircle(_newBitmap.getWidth() / 2, _newBitmap.getHeight() / 2,
                _newBitmap.getWidth() / 2.5f, _paint);

        _paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));

        _canvas.drawBitmap(_newBitmap, _rect, _rect, _paint);


        return _outBitmap;
    }

}
```

In the xml:

```
<com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgShot_shotDetail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
```

In the activity:

```
NetworkImageView imgShot = headerView.findViewById(R.id.imgShot_shotDetail);

imgShot.setImageUrl(url, AppControllerImage.getInstance().getImageLoader());
imgShot.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.notfound);
imgShot.setErrorImageResId(R.drawable.notfound);
```

In this case, I've used `NetworkImageView` from Volley library, but you can use a `ImageView` instead. You just have to adapt the code.